# Type as object reference in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, static-analysis

Is there a way in typescript to declare a function that returns **particular object**?

For instance, is there a way to declare a function which returns the same object as was passed inside?
Not the object *with the same structure* but actually the exactly same reference:

```js
function f(x : Object) : x {
    return x
}
```

Comment: No. That's not something that TypeScript can express. Can you explain your use case? This feels like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Not the reference, but you can ensure the type [like this playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFQHwAoAeiBciaAlAUYgN4CwAUIvYgE4CmUIjSOtAvkA)

Comment: @AluanHaddad, thanks. Please post it as answer so I can accept it.
My use case: I need to have a collection with several special values and I thought if I can use objects for this.
Upd: the example in question is not related but illustrates what kind of type checks I need.

Comment: @hopeless-programmer, not sure how I can answer. "No" isn't really worth an answer.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, I don't think so. I think it is very useful to know what You can and can't (in any way) do.

Answer (score -1):

```
const f = <T>(x: T): T => x;
```

That will infer the type T from x, which will be used as return type.

Comment: Also remember that TypeScript is the type layer on the top of JavaScript. It’s not involved in runtime operations (like accessing the particular object that will be part of the function invocation).

Comment: I don't need the type, I need the reference. As was stated in the question.
The same object, not the object with the same type.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a fixed object structure, you can cast the object structure as the type of the value regardless if it's a new value or a referenced value

```
interface selfDefinedStructure{
  id    : number;
  name  : string;
}

function ff(x : selfDefinedStructure){
    return x
}
```

using the sample below, typescript will recognize both **newValue** and **referenceValue** as valid regardless if it is passed as a new object or a referenced object. I also demonstrated by changing the name "DOC" to "dog"

```
var sample: selfDefinedStructure[]
  = [{id: 1, name: "cat"}, {id: 2, name: "DOC"}]

var newValue = ff({id: 99, name: "fish"})
var referenceValue = ff(sample[1])

referenceValue.name = "dog"

console.log(newValue)
console.log(sample[1])
```

Comment: This is not what I asked for.
In this case `ff()` can return something like `{ ...x }` - different object, different reference with the same type - and the translator will let it go.

Comment: As Aluan had answered, what u want to achieve is not possible. But i'll try to elaborate further using my own understanding.

Objects passed into function are always processes as a reference regardless if the object had been created prior of passing it as parameter.
What actually happen is that, javascript will first register the object into memory, then pass the reference as output.

Assuming u wish to prevent user from creating new object inside a parameter, nothing blocks user from first init the object with a random name then pass it back to the function
`var y = {...x}` then `ff(y)`

Comment: "Not possible" is a good answer.